# How to use camera in docker container

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I have a code in python that periodically takes pictures (using OpenCV). I created an image to execute this code in container. In linux, I can use it by perfectly executing the following command:

`docker run -it --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 myImage`

A little searching, the equivalent command in windows ( 10 Pro ) would be

`docker run --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb myImage`

But I am getting `Error response from daemon: Mount denied error`

I already tried to enable the shared drivers option in the Docker app, but the same error continued

I also tried some similar commands, but the same error continued

The command that generated a different error was:
`docker run -it --device /dev/video0 myImage`

generating the error:
  `Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "C": not a device node.`